# invoke WCF service on other machines on the same network not working

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a WCF Service running on my local machine

Everything themes to be running okay

**Question is**

if i can Invoke this `WCF` Service on my local machine browser 
why it is not available on other machines

*what i have tried :*

1. my service address was `localhost` : `port` on the other machine i replaced the localhost with the ip of the machine where my `WCF` service is running and it didn't work
2. in my `App.config` i changed the `baseaddress` as you can see below from `localhost` to the machine ip and it didn't work either
3. i created a web application and call my service using `getJson` and it worked on my local machine browser and not on any of the other machine it loads the whole page and gives me error on `getJson`

what i am missing here ??? i don't know

**IService1.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetName/{name}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Eval> GetName(string name);
```

**App.config**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"  targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress = "http://192.168.1.5:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**WCF Test Client**

[image]

**Browser**
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that firewall is not stopping you? Open inbound connection on port 8733 on machine where WCF is hosted.

Comment: Can you telnet into port 8733 from the other computer?

Comment: @kkokosa please have this comment as an answer with some instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that firewall is stopping service call. Open inbound connection on port 8733 on machine where WCF is hosted. In case of Windows, open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, and then, in the right pane, click New Rule and select Port option.